# How to validate input field starting from a yaml file

Tags: java, maven, yaml, swagger, openapi

I have a REST API defined in a swagger.yaml. Inside there are all the fields with their specifications (eg: length, pattern, etc.). Is there a way in java to validate these fields according to their specifications without having to do it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In this way I should go and set the annotation manually above each
> field, I was looking for a library that would automate everything by
> reading the rules on the swagger

Yes, the OpenApi tool generator is able to do that.

https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/jaxrs-spec

If the option "useBeanValidation" is enabled (default value), then the javax.validation annotations will be generated in your jaxrs bean.

Comment: I followed your suggestion and on my generated classes there are now annotations like Patter, Size, NotNull etc. But it seems these annotations don't work. Why?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to validate request bodies in controller level, you should check javax validation constrains https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/package-summary.html
There are plenty of annotations such as @NotNull, @Pattern @Max etc. which will do the job

Comment: In this way I should go and set the annotation manually above each field, I was looking for a library that would automate everything by reading the rules on the swagger